# Can anyone give me code example of how multiple outputs of a single fragment shader is recorded and how to read them seperately(VULKAN)

Tags: python, c++, vulkan

Take the fragment shader as example:

```
#version 450
//#extension GL_ARB_seperate_shader_objects : enable

layout(location = 0) in vec3 color1;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
layout(location = 1) out float outID;

void main() {
    
    outColor = vec4(color1, 1.0);
    outID = 0.7;
}
```

Now can anyone tell me how to record both the outputs of the fragment shader. Now for a single output (outColor) i know it can be read in a image format of size (width, height, 4) but as we have two outputs here (outColor, outID) how exactly the are to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output at location 0 goes to color attachment 0.

Output at location 1 goes to color attachment 1.

Teh spec ([Fragment Output Interface](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#interfaces-fragmentoutput)):

> A fragment shader output variable identified with a `Location` decoration of *i* is associated with the color attachment indicated by `pColorAttachments[i]`.

[VkSubpassDescription](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkSubpassDescription):

> Each element of the `pColorAttachments` array corresponds to an output location in the shader, i.e. if the shader declares an output variable decorated with a `Location` value of `X`, then it uses the attachment provided in `pColorAttachments[X]`.

Comment: So when Im copying it to cpu memory what color format i should use? Cos for attachment1 it is r8g8b8a8_unorm and for attachment2 it is r32_sfloat.

Comment: @AkshayakeerthiDuraisamy No color format. Use a buffer.